# Discord.py - VoiceClient. How can I call next audio file? play(source, *, after=None)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to do music discord bot using Discord.py 1.3.2.

As my queue I'm just using normal list. List keeps paths to .mp3 files. Self.vc is voice client. Everything works fine, until songs end. I was trying to figure it out myself, but I can't find the answer. How to call next "song"?

```
self.source = FFmpegPCMAudio(self.queue[0])
self.vc.play(self.source, after= what should be here?)
```

I was reading references and I don't understand what "(Callable[[Exception], Any])" means.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Since I've just got the same problem here is my solution.

Discord.Py API provides an FAQ with the same problem [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-pass-a-coroutine-to-the-player-s-after-function).

Basically you define your after function and use asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe to call everything.

Here's my code:

```
def playit():
    try:
        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(gPlaylist[0]), gVol)
        bot.voice_clients[0].play(source, after = myafter)
        gPlaylist.pop(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def myafter(error):
    try:
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(playit(), bot.loop)
        fut.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(gPlaylist[0]), gVol)
ctx.voice_client.play(source, after = myafter)
```

My full bot is [here](https://github.com/Polynomendivision/discord-helper-bot/blob/master/main.py).